# Set click button events in a loop

Tags: app-inventor

In my application MIT App Inventor, i created a function to click on the image:

```
to myfunc ( button )
  do ...
```

there are several buttons with the same actions:

```
when image1.Touched
  x  y
do call myfunc
          button( image1 )

when image2.Touched
  x  y
do call myfunc
          button( image2 )

when image3.Touched
  x  y
do call myfunc
          button( image3 )
...
```

I have 20 images. Can I set a click events for them inside a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call the same procedure in each button click event and pass the button id as input parameter

```
when button1.Click do 
  call myProcedure "1"...

when button2.Click do 
  call myProcedure "2"...

when button3.Click do 
  call myProcedure "3"...

when button4.Click do 
  call myProcedure "4"...
```

then in a for each loop you could do something like this (assuming there are 4 buttons) and pass the current number to the procedure

```
for each number from 1 to 4 do
  call procedure "number"
```

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: Can I create an array of buttons and change their properties: text, visibility, etc. in the procedure?

Comment: yes you can, see here how to work with the advanced blocks: https://puravidaapps.com/checkbox.php and https://puravidaapps.com/quiz.php